# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

Tags: php, header, xmlhttprequest, cors

У меня есть ссылка, но политикой CORS меня блокируют к доступу по этой ссылке,
как мне прочитать заголовок ответа, и понять что меня блокирую политикой CORS.
пробую вот так ничего не выходит.

```
$array_headers = get_headers("http://site.site"); 
print_r($array_headers);
if (in_array("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null", $array_headers)) 
{
echo "False";
}
else{
echo "true";
}

 Array ( 
[0] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
[1] => Date: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 19:29:20 GMT 
[2] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
[3] => Connection: close 
[4] => Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d0ee188841a0fc19bd26bd51c5e70d9f11584646159; expires=Sat, 18-Apr-20 19:29:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.tinyurl.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax 
[5] => X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.13 
[6] => Location: https://rt-cache1.peers.tv/streaming/dom_kino_premium/16/variable.m3u8 
[7] => Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, private 
[8] => Set-Cookie: tinyUUID=e73c8151874825d4056c0000; expires=Tue, 18-Mar-2025 19:29:20 GMT; Max-Age=157680000; path=/; domain=.tinyurl.com 
[9] => Set-Cookie: TCSR-b348b8474970ef668457d1b41722be83=eyJpdiI6Ilc1UEpqUGduSzVGUWpadElqN3g2Z0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSHg3YlRwYmJ4Z2xOaVhXM3hjejJ0QT09IiwibWFjIjoiZDIwNWNhZTUzZjQ2NjYwN2ZjMmRmOWU0NTc3ZGRlNTU5ZjM1N2IwMjY0NDBlYWRjMWU2ODFiMWVlNmU2NTljYSJ9; expires=Thu, 19-Mar-2020 19:34:20 GMT; Max-Age=300; path=/; domain=.tinyurl.com 
[10] => CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC 
[11] => Server: cloudflare 
[12] => CF-RAY: 57699a027ea57b87-DME 
[13] => alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-25=":443"; ma=86400, h3-24=":443"; ma=86400, h3-23=":443"; ma=86400 
[14] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
[15] => Server: nginx 
[16] => Date: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 19:29:20 GMT 
[17] => Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl 
[18] => Content-Length: 139 
[19] => Connection: close 
[20] => Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 19:28:10 GMT 
[21] => ETag: "5e73c7ca-8b" 
[22] => Expires: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 19:29:35 GMT 
[23] => Cache-Control: max-age=60 
[24] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
[25] => Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Inetra-Timeshift,Inetra-Timeshift-Offset,Date,Content-Range,Content-Length 
[26] => Vary: Origin 
[27] => Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true 
[28] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS 
[29] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range,Accept-Encoding 
[30] => X-CRP: dom_kino_premium_16_variable 
[31] => X-Upstream_cache_status: HIT 
[32] => Inetra-Timeshift: none 
[33] => Accept-Ranges: bytes )
```

Comment: `print_r($array_headers);` что выводит. Приложите к вопросу

Comment: он выводит, что есть  заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, но его нет, это я точно знаю. Мне надо узнать есть ли в  заголовке разрешение на подгруздку данных с сервера или нет, т.е

Comment: мне не нужны ваши слова. Отредактируйте вопрос, вставив туда вывод `print_r($array_headers);`. И вы должны быть в курсе, что CORS не завязан с php от слова совсем. Проблемы будут с js

Comment: вставил вывод с print_r

Comment: Вам пришёл ответ **301 Moved Permanently**, что означает перенаправление. Т.е. всё работает штатно. Потом **200 OK**, что тоже говорит об успешности выполнения. Откуда вы вообще взяли, что CORS что-то блокирует?

Comment: Это ссылка на поток m3u8, я использую hls.js и при воспроизведении таких потоков, в консолt браузера выскакивает ошибка связана с CORS.